# Independence in functional theoretic view on probability

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, hilbert-spaces, conditional-probability, independence

I'm reading the book *Hilbert Space Methods in Probability and Statistical Inference* by *Small and McLeish*.

There (Def. 3.2.4) **independence** is defines as follows

> Let $\mathbf{B}$ and $\mathbf{C}$ be two sets of random variables. The sets $\mathbf{B}$ and $\mathbf{C}$ are said to be *independent* if
> $$\langle \mathbf{x} - \mathbb{E}(\mathbf{x} )\mathbf{1},  \mathbf{y} - \mathbb{E}(\mathbf{y} )\mathbf{1}\rangle =0$$
> for all $\mathbf{x} \in ps(B)$ and all $\mathbf{y} \in ps(C)$. In particular, if $\mathbf{B}=\{\mathbf{x}\}$ and $\mathbf{C}=\{\mathbf{y}\}$, then we say that $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ are independent. Random variables $\{\mathbf{x}_{\alpha}\}$ are said to be *mutually independent* if any two disjoint subcollections of the random variables are independent. Similarly events $\{\mathbf{A}_{\alpha}\}$ are said to be *mutually independent* if their corresponding indicators are mutually independent.

The authors claim, that this definition immediately implies $$P\left( \bigwedge_{i=1}^{n}A_{i} \right)=\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n}P(A_{i}) $$ for mutually independent events $A_{1},A_{2},\ldots, A_{n}$.

While I think the proof for arbitrary $n$ follows easily by induction, I'm stuck in proving the result for $n=2$.

From the definition, two events $A$ and $B$ are mutually independent if:
$$\begin{align}
\langle \mathbf{1}_{A} - \mathbb{E}(\mathbf{1}_{A} )\mathbf{1},  \mathbf{1}_{B} \mathbb{E}(\mathbf{1}_{B} )\mathbf{1}\rangle 
&=
\langle \mathbf{1}_{A} , \mathbf{1}_{B} \rangle
-
\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{1}_{B})\langle\mathbf{1}_{A} ,\mathbf{1} \rangle
-
\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{1}_{A})\langle\mathbf{1}_{B} ,\mathbf{1} \rangle
+
\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{1}_{A})\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{1}_{B})\langle \mathbf{1} ,\mathbf{1}\rangle\\
&=
\langle \mathbf{1}_{A} , \mathbf{1}_{B} \rangle 
-
2\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{1}_{A})\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{1}_{B})
+
\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{1}_{A})\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{1}_{B})\\
&=
\langle \mathbf{1}_{A} , \mathbf{1}_{B} \rangle 
-
\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{1}_{A})\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{1}_{B})\\
&=
0
\end{align}$$
Therefore
$$\langle \mathbf{1}_{A} , \mathbf{1}_{B} \rangle =\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{1}_{A})\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{1}_{B})$$
implies independence.

Furthermore, also be definition, $P(A):=\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{1}_{A})$. The last equality is therefore equivalent to
$$\langle \mathbf{1}_{A} , \mathbf{1}_{B} \rangle 
=
P(\mathbf{A})P(\mathbf{B})$$

However to complete the proof $P(A \bigwedge B)=\langle \mathbf{1}_{A} , \mathbf{1}_{B} \rangle $ must hold.
But by definition $$P\left(A \bigwedge B\right)=\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{1}_{A\bigwedge B})=\langle \mathbf{1}_{A}\mathbf{1}_{B},\mathbf{1} \rangle$$.

If we consider the Hilbert Space $L^{2}([0,1])$ this follows from the definition of $\langle f,g\rangle :=\int_{[0,1]}f(x)g(x)dx$ since
$$
\langle \mathbf{1}_{A}\mathbf{1}_{B},\mathbf{1}\rangle
=
\int_{[0,1]}\mathbf{1}_{A}(x)\mathbf{1}_{B}(x)\mathbf{1}_{[0,1]}(x)dx
=
\int_{[0,1]}\mathbf{1}_{A}(x)\mathbf{1}_{B}(x)(x)dx
=
\langle \mathbf{1}_{A},\mathbf{1}_{B}\rangle
$$

But I do not see why $$\langle\mathbf{1}_{A}\mathbf{1}_{B},\mathbf{1} \rangle=\langle \mathbf{1}_{A} , \mathbf{1}_{B}\rangle$$ should hold in general? I assume I'm missing some property of inner products.

Comment: Why do you have $\mathbb E[\mathbf 1_A \mathbf 1_B] = \langle\mathbf 1_A \mathbf 1_B, \mathbf 1\rangle$ ?

Comment: $\mathbb{E}$ is defined as a functional on a Hilbert Space $H$ via $\mathbb{E}(x)=\langle \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{1} \rangle$ for $x \in H$. $\mathbf{1}$ is an unitary element in this Hilbert Space that satisfies $\langle \mathbf{1},\mathbf{1}\rangle=1$. Therefore $\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{1}_{A}\mathbf{1}_{B})=\langle \mathbf{1}_{A}\mathbf{1}_{B},\mathbf{1}\rangle$ by definition of $\mathbb{E}$

Comment: Ok and is the product $\mathbf x \mathbf y$ defined for any $\mathbf x$ and $\mathbf y$ in $H$ ? What properties does it satisfy ?

Comment: Interesting point. But no, there is no definition of a product $\mathbf{x}\mathbf{y}$. However to prove $\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{1}_{A}\mathbf{1}_B)=\langle \mathbf{1}_{A},\mathbf{1}_{B}\rangle$ is left as an exercise to the reader in problem 18 of the book. I guess the first step is then to prove that $\mathbf{1}_{A \wedge B}=\mathbf{1}_{A}\mathbf{1}_{B}$.

Comment: If there's no definition of a product then $\mathbf 1_A \mathbf 1_B$ doesn't make sense, no ? By the way I think you forgot a $``=0"$ in your definition of independence

Comment: M&S define the indicator variable $\mathbf{1}_A$ (paraphrasing slightly) as a function $[0,1]\to \{0,1\}$ such that $x\mapsto 1$ if $x\in A$ and $x\mapsto 0$ otherwise. So  $(\mathbf{1}_A \mathbf{1}_B)(x)=1$ iff $x\in A \wedge x\in B$, i.e., $x\in A\wedge B$.

Comment: @StratosFair Yes and no. In general you are right, however since this is a problem from the book, I assume there must be a solution. I guess by defining a product only for indicators one can find a way.

Comment: @Semiclassical you were faster. This definition is what I had in mind since this definition is similar to characteristic functions defined over sets.